# SamAccountName in Azure ADDS

Tags: azure-ad-domain-services

Is it possible to retrieve SamAccountName in Azure ADDS?

For example, John join company A as john@a.com, there is a child domain called A1, another John joins in as John@a1.com the UPN works fine, but SamAccountName will be different as per screenshot in Azure ADDS.

in VS, there is only UserID, which is the SamAccountName, so I need to get this SamAccountName automatically.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4tvp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ZMg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just install AD powershell on one of the domain server and wrote a script to pull the Sam name

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id. What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??